# Data extraction manipulation using awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I have a snort.rule file, I need to extract cve numbers followed by reference key from the line and append them back in **msg** field of the same line inside flower brackets, below is the old log.

> alert udp $HOME_NET 1900 -> any any (msg:"ET INFO UPnP Discovery Search Response vulnerable UPnP device 2"; content:"Intel SDK for UPnP devices"; pcre:"/^Server\x3a[^\r\n]*Intel SDK for UPnP devices/mi"; reference: /infosec/blog/2013/01/29; reference:arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf; reference:cve,2012-5958; reference:cve,2012-5959;sid:2016303; rev:4;)

Required output is below, bold ones are the new changes,

> alert udp $HOME_NET 1900 -> any any (msg:"ET INFO UPnP Discovery Search Response vulnerable UPnP device 2 **{cve,2012-5958 cve,2012-5959}**"; content:"Intel SDK for UPnP devices"; pcre:"/^Server\x3a[^\r\n]*Intel SDK for UPnP devices/mi"; reference: /infosec/blog/2013/01/29; reference: arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf; reference:cve,2012-5958; reference:cve,2012-5959;sid:2016303; rev:4;)

I do have issue with the awk code below, it is removing semicolon between all keys while displaying back the results, last sub function is culprit, I need to correct the below code:

```
awk -F\; '
{
  for ( i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++ ) {
    if ( $i ~ "msg" )
      a = i
    if ( $i ~ "reference:cve," ) {
      b = $i
      sub ( ".*:" , "" , b )
      c = c " " b 
      }
    }
  sub ( "$" , "{" c "\"}" , $a )
} 1' snort.rule
```

Comment: @Thor the old brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `perl` here

```
perl -pe '$" = " "; @cves = /reference:\s*(cve,\d+-\d+)/g;
   s/msg:\s*"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*\K/ {@cves}/ if (@cves)'
```

Also handling `msg`s with embedded `\"`.

Comment: your solution worked Thankyou. Any idea on above awk code can you help to resolve the second sub() call why it omitting semicolon between keys while displaying back results.